# Understanding Rails date in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a date from a user and send it inside an email as plain text in the following format: "07/30/2015".

In order to do that, if the output I am getting is a string, I could just do:

```
Date.parse("2015-07-30").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

The problem is, I am getting a FixNum.

The issues are many:

- If I try to convert to a string to parse it with `Date.parse`, it becomes "2001".
- If I apply the code I just wrote, `Date.parse`... it will throw 'invalid date'.

For instance:

```
(2016-02-13).to_s #=> "2001"

(2016-02-13).to_date #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' for 2001:Fixnum

Date.parse("2001").strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #=> invalid date
```

So if I can convert `2015-07-30` into `"2015-07-30"`, it would work:

```
Date.parse("2015-07-30").strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #=> "07/30/2015"
```

Then I tried using `date_select` instead of `date_field`, but now the message arrives with those fields empty.

Any suggestions?

Here is my form:

```
= form_for @contact do |f|
    = f.text_field :product_name
    = f.date_field :purchase_date
    = f.submit
```

Here is my code:

```
<%= message.subject %>

<% @resource.mail_form_attributes.each do |attribute, value|
    if attribute == "mail_subject" 
        next
    end
%>

<%= "#{@resource.class.human_attribute_name(attribute)}: #{Date.parse(value).class == Date ? Date.parse(value).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") : value}" %>

<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :send_email, except: [:create]

    def create
       @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
       @contact.request = request
       if @contact.deliver
           @thank   = "Thank you for your message!"
           @message = "We have received your inquiry and we'll be in touch shortly."
       else
           @error   = "Cannot send message. Please, try again."
       end
    end

    def contact_page
    end

    def product_complaint
        @the_subject = "Product Complaint Form"
    end


    private
        def send_email
            @contact = Contact.new
        end
end
```

My model:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base

   # all forms
   attribute :mail_subject
   attribute :first_name,             validate: true
   attribute :last_name,              validate: true

   # product-complaint
   attribute :best_by,                validate: true, allow_blank: true # date
   attribute :bag_code,               validate: true, allow_blank: true
   attribute :purchase_date,          validate: true, allow_blank: true # date
   attribute :bag_opened,             validate: true, allow_blank: true # date
   attribute :problem_noticed,        validate: true, allow_blank: true # date

   # all forms
   attribute :message,                validate: true
   attribute :nickname,               captcha:  true

   def headers
       {
           content_type: "text/plain",
           subject: %(#{mail_subject}),
           to:      "xxxxx@xxxxxxx.com",
           # from:    %("#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}" <#{email.downcase}>)
           from: "xxx@xxxxx.com"

       }
   end
 end
```

Comment: How are you storing the data submitted by the form?

Comment: can you post the `mail_form_attributes`  method. i assume the date youre trying to parse is one of the key-values youre iterating over? the controller action will be useful as well

Comment: I am using the gem mail_form and I am modifying the default source. I will put the whole code now in my question.

Comment: Could you show use what is posted to the controller, because it should just be a string if you are using a `text_field`.

Comment: I am using form_form  f.date_field

Comment: what are the params that come to the create route?

Comment: I guess the params are the attributes I am setting in the Contact Model. I don't have contact_params because the truth is, this is just a contact form that sends an email so I am not storing those messages. The problem comes because my client needs the email to arrive with dates formatted : 07/30/2015 and I am getting the fixnum 2015-07-30. So it performs the subtraction before doing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not understanding something about receiving values from forms: You can NOT receive an integer, a fixnum or anything else other than strings. So, you can't have received `2016-02-13`. Instead you got `"2016-02-13"` or `"2016"`, `"02"` or `"2"` and `"13"` depending on the form. If you're running under Rails, then it got the strings, and through its meta-data understands you want an integer (which really should probably be defined as a string), and it converts it to an integer for you.

Either way, when you write:

```
(2016-02-13).to_s
(2016-02-13).to_date
```

you're propagating that misunderstanding into your testing. This is how it *MUST* be written because you need to be working with strings:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'

("2016-02-13").to_s # => "2016-02-13"
("2016-02-13").to_date # => #<Date: 2016-02-13 ((2457432j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

You can create dates without them being strings though: Ruby's `Date` initializer allows us to pass the year, month and day value and receive a new Date object:

```
year, month, day = 2001, 1, 2
date = Date.new(year, month, day) # => #<Date: 2001-01-02 ((2451912j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.year # => 2001
date.month # => 1
date.day # => 2
```

Moving on...

Parsing dates in Ruby quickly demonstrates it's not a U.S.-centric language. Americans suppose all dates of 01/01/2001 are in "MM/DD/YYYY" but that's a poor assumption because much of the rest of the world uses "DD/MM/YYYY". Not knowing that means that code written under that assumption is doing the wrong thing. Consider this:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.parse('01/02/2001') 
date.month # => 2
date.day # => 1
```

Obviously something "wrong" is happening, at least for 'mericans. This is very apparent with:

```
date = Date.parse('01/31/2001') 
# ~> -:3:in `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
```

This occurs because there is no month "31". In the previous example of `'01/02/2001'`, that misunderstanding means the programmer thinks it should be "January 2" but the code thinks it's "February 1", and work with that. That can cause major havoc in an enterprise system, or anything dealing with financial calculations, product scheduling, shipping or anything else that works with dates.

Because the code is assuming DD/MM/YYYY format for that sort of string, the sensible things to do are:

- KNOW what format your users are going to send dates in. Don't assume, ever. ASK them and make your code capable of dealing with alternates, or tell them what they MUST use and vet out their data prior to actually committing it to your system. Or, provide a GUI that forces them to pick their dates from popups and never allows them to enter it by hand.
- Force the date parser to use explicit formats of dates so it can always do the right thing:

  ```
  Date.strptime('01/31/2001', '%m/%d/%Y') # => #<Date: 2001-01-31 ((2451941j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  Date.strptime('31/01/2001', '%d/%m/%Y') # => #<Date: 2001-01-31 ((2451941j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
  ```

The last point is the crux of writing code: We're telling the language what to do, not subjecting ourselves, and our employers, to code that's guessing. Give code half a chance and it'll do the wrong thing, so you control it. That's why programming is hard.

Comment: Tin Man, thanks for the input, but unfortunately I already knew all this and that is exactly why I am amazed by the fact that the value I am getting as a result of choosing a date from the date picker provided by Rails form_for f.date_field, is a FixNum instead of a String. On top of that I'm not american, so I understand dates are different. I have a contact form that is not attached to ActiveRecord, so there is no persistence in a database. The user chooses a date in a date_field and the value I am getting back is simply 2015-08-02, not "2015-08-02". Anyways, I appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: @drjorgepolanco Unfortunately what you're saying is impossible. There is NO WAY in Ruby to receive an integer in any other form than a whole number. If you see "2015-08-02" outputted anywhere in your application it is 100% certain it is not an integer. There is some sort of very basic misunderstanding you have about how Ruby or Rails behaves here. The problem is for us to figure out what it is so that we can help you. I suggest you reread Tin Man's answer to make sure you completely understand what he said.

Comment: Thanks Casper, I also thought that it was impossible, but this is what I am getting: you choose a date from the date picker and the value I am getting on the other side is FixNum 2015-08-02, I am NOT getting "2015-08-02", so I am not able to parse it as a date. If I try to manipulate that value as a string, it throws an error because it is not a string. Thanks everyone for your time, I really appreciate.

Comment: @drjorgepolanco I assure you it's not a FixNum. You should do `logger.info @date_variable.class`, and you will see it is not a FixNum.

Answer (score 3):

```
(2016-02-13).to_date #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_date' for 2001:Fixnum
```

youre getting this error because you dont have quotes around the value. i.e. its not a string, its a number that is having subtraction applied to it. this is being interpreted as

```
2016 - 2
2014 - 13
2001.to_date
```

it needs to be `('2016-02-13').to_date`

if youre unable to get it as a string, can you post how you're getting it from the user to begin with? (a date field ought to be sending you a string to your controller, not a series of numbers)

Comment: Hey Phil! Thanks for the input. I knew that, but this is exactly the problem that I haven't been able to convert that 2015-07-30 to "2015-07-30" on the fly.
I updated my code so you can have a better look.

Comment: @drjorgepolanco I don't understand; where is "2015-07-30" coming from? That `value` from the iteration? If it's a string, it's a string. If it's not, then there's the root of your issue. It's not getting magically evaled on its own.

Comment: 2015-07-30 is not a string, for some reason when you choose a date in date_field the output is 2015-07-30, which is a FixNum.

Comment: @drjorgepolanco can you just call `.to_s` first?

Comment: I tried that too. When you call to_s that is the output:

        (2016-02-13).to_s #=> "2001"