# Convert date to string without applying substraction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to convert 2015-08-02 into "2015-08-2" with Ruby. If I do:

```
(2015-08-02).to_s => SyntaxError: (irb):21: Invalid octal digit

2015-08-02.to_s => SyntaxError: (irb):21: Invalid octal digit
```

Comment: A date isn't represented by `2015-08-02`. It can start as a String: `"2015-08-02"` and then be parsed into a string. I'd strongly suggest reading the Time and Date/DateTime documentation.

Comment: `2015-08-02` is not a valid date literal. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Take a look at this problem, this is what I am trying to resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729471/understanding-rails-date-in-form-for

Comment: How do you collect input from user such that you get FixNum?  Not sure your other SO problem is any clearer

Comment: I am using form_for  f.date_field. I should be getting a string back, but I am getting a fixnum. The problem is the user chooses a date and in the input form I have 08/02/2015, but in the email I still get 2015-08-02. And the client needs to get the first format, because he has another app in place that parses those dates in the emails he receives.

Comment: what is the value of that fixnum?  Do you know how RAILs send date value from form - have you reviewed this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#barebones-helpers?

Comment: The value of that FixNum is just the date: 2015-08-02. What is happing is that when I try to manipulate that date it applies a substraction: 2015 - 08, and then - 02.

Comment: "The value of that FixNum is just the date: 2015-08-02". A FixNum *CAN'T* be a date, especially like "2015-08-02". It *could* represent the number of seconds from a given starting point, such as a POSIX date : `Time.at(1438498800) # => 2015-08-02 00:00:00 -0700`

Comment: You are right Tin Man. I was trying to apply string methods to that date and that was the error I was getting: Fixnum can't be coerced into...; but after yours and Casper's comments, I evaluated the value itself and it is indeed a String. I just don't understand why I am not being able to manipulate the value, but probably I am doing something wrong. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediate on this:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.parse('2015-08-02') # => #<Date: 2015-08-02 ((2457237j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

At this point the string containing the date has been parsed into a Date object.

```
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%e') # => "2015-08- 2"
```

`date` can be returned to a string using [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime), which has a number of ways of representing the various parts of the date. In this case you don't want a zero-padded day. Ruby supports using `%e` which is a space-padded day, but then you have the space to deal with:

```
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%e').delete(' ') # => "2015-08-2"
```

Comment: Thanks Tin Man. I knew that doing Date.parse("2015-08-02").strftime("%m/%d/%Y") => "08/02/2015". The problem is that I am receiving 2015-08-02 as a FixNum.

Comment: You can write  `date.strftime('%Y-%m-%-d') #=> "2015-08-2"` or  `date.strftime('%Y-%m-%-e') #=> "2015-08-2"`. This uses [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)'s `-` flag ("don't pad a numerical output").

Comment: Good catch! I was thinking that but then said "Naw, that has to only apply to format strings and didn't look at the esoterica about `strftime`.